# Not able to start airflow webserver in background in docker

Tags: docker, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I am trying to run airflow on an anaconda3 docker image. Everything is working fine, except I am not able to run airflow webserver and scheduler in the background using:

```
airflow webserver -D
airflow scheduler -D
```

Both of them start in the foreground and I have to open a new terminal for them to run.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/17185).

Tl:dr - It works when using the official airflow image.